# Puma and Nginx 502 Bad Gateway error (Ubuntu Server 14.04)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, puma

I need to deploy my rails application,So I have followed all step from here, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

But end of the tutorial, I get this error --> "502 Bad Gateway"

**EDIT**
The error message now --> "We're sorry, but something went wrong."
But Nginx error output is the same, I check puma error messages but they just log when it start and when it stop gracefully.

Rails logs which is under app_directory/log   does not produce any output.
puma-manager --> I checked it works correctly
paths       ---> I have checked three times

Nginx error.log output message:

```
2016/05/18 14:22:21 [crit] 1099#0: *7 connect() to unix:/home/deploy   /hotel-automata/shared/sockets/puma.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.2.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/deploy/hotel-automata/shared/sockets/puma.sock:/500.html", host: "192.168.2.170"
```

OS -> Vmware Player, Bridged Network Ubuntu Server 14.0.4
Ruby Version: 2.3.1
Rails Version: 4.2.5.2

This is my nginx config contents of  /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
upstream app {
# Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
server unix:/home/deploy/hotel-automata/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

root /home/deploy/hotel-automata/public;

try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

location @app {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 4G;
keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: i dont have any knowledge about puma. But have you tried to change the permissions of `puma.sock` file? I used to get this kind of error when i used `uwsgi` with `nginx`

Comment: Post your nginx config

Comment: @dan-klasson I have added nginx config

Comment: @manojprashantk there is no puma.sock file in the directory.

Comment: I may be wrong but can you change `unix:/home/deploy/hotel-automata/shared/sockets/puma.sock` to `unix:///home/deploy/hotel-automata/shared/sockets/puma.sock` and try

Comment: check my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810338/puma-sock-missing-in-ec2-server-after-capistrano-deployment/48476580#48476580

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:**

1. **Make user that the socket exist**. Otherwise it's failing on this point:

in `config/puma.rb` you need to have line pointing to your socket:

```
bind "unix://<path or variable for the path where the socket will be>/sockets/puma.sock"
```

example with variable:

```
application_path = '/home/deploy/hotel-automata/shared'

bind "unix://#{application_path}/sockets/puma.socket"
```

2. **Check permissions on the socket**

You will need to make sure that Nginx is able to access your socket (have the required rights i.e. RW)

The check the permissions on the whole path try this:

`namei -m /home/deploy/hotel-automata/shared/sockets/puma.sock`

Alternatively try this:

```
sudo -u <user> test <-r / -w > <path> && echo True
```

i.e.

```
sudo -u nginx test -w /home/deploy/hotel-automata/shared/sockets/puma.sock && echo True
```

**Nginx will require RW access to that socket.**

If it doesn't return true then it means that the user **has NOT got** that permission i.e. -w -> write

Comment: There is no gap in my socket path, Do you mean something different?

Comment: Well had to edit my answer as you provided new data, check the permissions and let me know.

Comment: There is no puma.sock file under the directory. should it generated automatically?  @MichaIT

Comment: When puma starts it should create a socket. This is where you configure it:
`vi config/puma.rb` `# Set up socket location
bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"`

Comment: Just make sure that in `config/puma.rb` you have `bind "unix://<path to your socket>/sockets/puma.sock"` then restart your puma. It's very difficult to walk someone through the comment box. I'll edit the answer again

Answer (score 2):

Your `puma.rb` file should look like this.

```
# /config/puma.rb

  app = "manabalss" # App-specific
  root = "/home/deployer/apps/#{app}"

  workers  5
  threads  1, 1 # relying on many workers for thread-unsafe apps

  rackup      DefaultRackup
  port        11592
  environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'production'
  daemonize   true

  pidfile "#{root}/puma/puma.pid"
  stdout_redirect "#{root}/puma/puma.log", "#{root}/puma/puma_error.log"
  bind "unix:/tmp/puma.socket
```

And your nginx.conf should be like this.

```
# config/deploy/nginx.conf

upstream puma {
  server unix:/tmp/puma.socket fail_timeout=1;
}

# This block redirects http requests to https version 
server {
  listen 37.139.0.211:80 default deferred;
  server_name www.manabalss.lv, manabalss.lv;
  return 307  https://manabalss.lv$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen                37.139.0.211:443 ssl;
  server_name           manabalss.lv;
  ssl_certificate       /etc/ssl/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/server.key;
  ssl_protocols         SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers           RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_session_cache     shared:SSL:15m;
  ssl_session_timeout   15m;

  root /home/deployer/apps/manabalss/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_vary on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_pass        http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

If this doesn't help, you would like to have a look at this.

[Rails + Puma + Nginx Every Bad Gateway 502](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596118/rails-puma-nginx-every-couple-of-days-bad-gateway-502)

Comment: Thanks subhash, I am starting to try now