# foreman start doesn't seem to bind puma socket in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, foreman

I'm working a Rails application ran into some problems with a 502 error when I tried to go to our staging site. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298451/puma-and-nginx-502-bad-gateway-error-ubuntu-server-14-04) had the answer I needed by adding to puma.rb:

```
application_path = '/home/deploy/hotel-automata/shared'

bind "unix://#{application_path}/sockets/puma.socket"
```

I was also able to start the server in development by running `foreman start -p 3000`. The question I have is how does this not throw an error? The `application_path` I have definitely doesn't exist in my local computer and running `bundle exec puma` or `bundle exec rails server` threw an error on `file not found`. Is this something that's specific to foreman or am I missing something?  I looked around for a while but couldn't find anything related to this.

Also, is this the best way to do this? I feel that using an exact path might not be the best way here but I'm not sure what else I should do. Any suggestions on this point would be much appreciated too.

Also, here's my `Procfile`:

```
web:      bundle exec rails server
redis:    redis-server
sidekiq:  bundle exec sidekiq
```